# Google Cloud SQL Activation Policy Menu

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

According to this link in the FAQ of Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#activation_policy I should find an option to change the Activation Policy, but in my console I can't find such option.

Can anyone share a capture of the option, or a way to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Second Generation instances the activation policy can only be `ALWAYS` or `NEVER`. Thus, you change it in the Cloud Console [by starting or stopping](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#activation-policy-2ndgen) the instance.

For First Generation instances the activation policy can be `ALWAYS`, `ON-DEMAND` or `NEVER`. You modify this by changing the Settings of the Instance on Cloud Console.

Also, for both First and Second generation instances, you could modify the activation policy by running `gcloud sql instances patch [instance name] --activation-policy [always, never, on-demand]`.

Comment: I thought the policies allow to an instance turn on when needed. I guess I got that wrong, haven't I?

Comment: It does, in First Generation. In Second Generation you can only have it always on or off.

Comment: I have added more information to my answer as I see I didn't fully explain it.